# Invoke azure B2C "Reset Password" flow from a button inside the applcation after user is signed in

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using **Azure B2C SignIn user flow** to sign in users, and with this flow I can reset user's password through "Forgot your password?" link:

```
https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_default/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?claimsexchange=ForgotPassword&csrf_token=............=B2C_1_default
```

I want to invoke/redirect the user to the previous link ("Forgot your password?" flow) **after** the user is signed in **by pressing a "Reset password" button from inside the application**.

I have been researching for some hours now but it's not clear how this specific functionality could be implemented.

Comment: Why not create a separate forgot password user flow and launch that from your app? You can’t deep link into the forgot password flow that’s part of the sign in flow. Other option is custom policy, which you can achieve this by passing a query param to the sign in flow.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Let's say I do have a reset password flow. How to launch it from inside my app?

Comment: You just call MSAL acquireTokenRedirect() and pass in the authority parameter for password reset policy instead of sign in policy.